# Running tests in monorepo with root babel configuration

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, lerna

When it comes to monorepos maintainers typically add all their `devDependencies` to the root of the repo, then when the root is installed they are installed at the root (`hoisted`), you are unable to access babel plugins and `.bin` modules from within each individual package.

I am trying to run `jest` at the root level of my lerna monorepo, and when I do so I get an error mentioned that a `babel` plugin is not available, this is because the individual packages each have their own babel configuration and babel is not looking in the root of the monorepo for these plugins.

How do I run `jest` within my monorepo and have `jest` use the babel config at root and not call plugins to be located relative to the individual packages?

```
 FAIL  packages/pkg-plugin-cobalt/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-object-rest-spread" specified in "/Users/thomas/Desktop/github.com/reggi/a
bide/packages/pkg-plugin-cobalt/package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/thomas/Desktop/github.com/r
eggi/abide/packages/pkg-plugin-cobalt"
```

Comment: I believe this works out of the box, this package was not installed at root.